# How to avoid incorrect deny in Firebase RTDB rules?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Firebase is refusing to read from the database right after the web authentication process. If I reload the page and log in again, it does not reject it.

The error message that appears is:

> Error: permission_denied at /sandboxusers/KEY_USER_ID/companies:
> Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

The security rules I have for sandbox users are:

```
     "sandboxusers" : {
       "$user_id" : {
         ".read": "auth != null",
         ".write": false
       }
     },
```

As a workaround I have done the following:

1. Change ".read" to false. In this case the code runs fine, but anyone could read it, which would not be appropriate for security.
2. Keep the original security rule, but include a delay right after the authentication process. In this case the code runs fine, but it would not be the correct way and could be an unreliable process.

The code that I am using in the authentication process is the following:

```
     Map info = await userProvider.signIn(user.user!, user.password!);

     if (info['ok']) {
       await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {}); //Delay that I would like to avoid
       Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('parameters', (route) => false); //To go to the parameters page where we try to read the DB
     } else {
       //Messages if authentication failed
     }
```

`userProvider.signIn`, is a function that returns 'ok': true if the authentication by email and password in Firebase is successful as follows:

```
  Future <Map<String, dynamic>> signIn(String email, String password) async {
   
    try {
       UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
       User user = result.user!;
       return {'ok' : true, 'localId': user.uid, 'email' : user.email};
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
         log('$e');
       return {'ok': false, 'code': e.code, 'message': '${e.message}' };
    }
  }
```

How can I correct the code to keep the security rule for authentication and remove the delay that I used as workaround?

UPDATE:
I tried to use a callback before reading, but it didn't work

```
    if (info['ok']) {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('parametros', (route) => false);
        }
      });

    } else {
      //Messages if Authentication failed
}
```

Comment: If the sign-in process says it's complete, but it doesn't allow access to security rules immediately, maybe that's a bug you should file with the dart SDK. It's considered a bad practice to wait indefinitely for something to happen - a callback should let you know when it's complete.

Comment: All that said, maybe you should be using an auth state listener to know when the sign in is fully complete. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#auth-state

Comment: Tks @doug, I tried to use a callback (`FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()`) before reading, but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you could show that code as well?

Comment: At a quick glance, none of the code you shared so far calls an API of the Firebase Realtime Database, so none of this code can raise the error you're asking about. That makes it hard to say what's going wrong, except what the error message already tells you. --- I recommend [reproducing the problem in a single snippet of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that any of us can then copy/paste to also get the same error. So don't copy/paste the snippets from your existing app, but try to reproduce it in a new piece of code/app - by calling the minimal set of APIs with minimal dependencies.